# Tabs don't work from a child Fragment navigated from one of the tabs

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

I'm working on an Android App and I already have 3 tabs working using Fragments for each tab. In one of the tabs (Tab3Fragment) I navigate to another fragment (NewExampleFragment).
The problem occurs when I try to navigate back from the child fragment (NewExampleFragment) to a tab fragment (Tab3Fragment). The tabs are visible from the child fragment, but clicking on them does nothing. I want to be able to access these 3 tabs from the child fragment. How to make it work?

The hierarchy is: AppCompatActivity -> Fragment (tabs) -> Child Fragment (from here I want to access the tabs again)

Activity:

```
public class WordPageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_word_page);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_word_page);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), android.R.id.tabcontent);
    mTabHost.addTab(
            mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator(getString(R.string.tab1_text), null),
            Tab1Fragment.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(
            mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator(getString(R.string.tab2_text), null),
            Tab2Fragment.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(
            mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab3").setIndicator(getString(R.string.tab3_text), null),
            Tab3Fragment.class, null);
}
```

Activity layout:

```
<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame_word_page"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

   <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_word_page"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

One of the tabs:

```
public class Tab3Fragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab3, container, false);

    Button openExamplePage = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.openExamplePageButton);
    openExamplePage.setOnClickListener(this);

    return v;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.openExamplePageButton:
            onOpenExamplePage(v);
            break;

    }
}

public void onOpenExamplePage(View v){
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame_word_page, new NewExampleFragment()).commit();
}
```

}

The child fragment:

```
public class NewExampleFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener  {

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_new_example, container, false);


    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: Try to use `TabLayout`. And this link will help you. https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-tablayout-example-using-viewpager-fragments/

Comment: Just Make one container inside `NewExampleFragment`. Then first time, load parent fragment on click change it to child and then back press switch that to parent.

Answer (score 0):

I tried TabLayout, but the problem remained the same. However, I resolved it by changing the layout I was replacing in onOpenExamplePage method:

```
public void onOpenExamplePage(View v){
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.tabcontent, new NewExampleFragment()).commit();
}
```

It should be android.R.id.tabcontent instead of R.id.content_frame_word_page as in the Activity layout the part I want to replace is

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

not the whole LinearLayout.